# Change the type of a MongoDB field to integer from its console

Tags: javascript, c++, mongodb

We have an application that stores some configuration values from C/C++ in MongoDB and has the   capability to be restarted (i.e. it runs for a while, someone interrupts the application, changes the configuration, then runs the app again, and it picks up where it left off). This works like a charm for boolean and string configurations.

But then we have some integers (in our current  C/C++ implementation - 32 bit values). And when I use the MongoDB console to modify those integer values, Mongo always stores them back as Number (which is doulble in the C/C++ implementation). We will change the app to take double values where it expects integers but I was wondering if there is a way to force Mongo to store integers from its JavaScript console.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Resave the values as using parseFloat() or just don't put any speech marks around the value

Comment: Actually try parseInt() sorry

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the C/C++ "sense of the word", ints are [not actually guaranteed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/size-of-int-long-etc?answertab=votes#tab-top) to be 32-bit values.  An `int` must be at least 16-bits, but generally matches the platform architecture (eg. 32 or 64bit).

As mentioned by @Jasd, JavaScript does only have one numeric type which is a floating point (`double` in C).

From the MongoDB shell you should be able to use the functions `NumberInt(..)` to get a [BSON 32-bit integer value](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification) or `NumberLong(..)` to get a BSON 64-bit integer.

Comment: nice catch about the int size!

Answer (score 9):

You can fix the types of all values for a certain field on the console with something like:

```
db.Statistic.find({kodoId: {$exists: true}}).forEach(function (x) {
  x.kodoId = NumberInt(x.kodoId);
  db.Statistic.save(x);
});
```

This will only load documents that have the `kodoId` field and convert them to int and resave. You could do something like:

```
db.Statistic.find({kodoId: {$exists: true}}, {kodoId: 1}).forEach(function (x) {
   db.Statistic.update({ _id: x._id },
      {$set: {
        kodoId: NumberInt(x.kodoId)
      }});
});
```

with a second param which will *only* load the kodoId value (hopefully from an index). This should be much quicker since it doesn't need to load and resave the entire document - just that one field.

Comment: You might was to add a `try .. catch (err)` around the 2nd example in case there are some values which are already NumberInt since it will throw an error.

Comment: Worked like a charm for me. Thanks!

Comment: I came back to this answer more than I llike to admit...

Comment: Only one observation, do NOT mix first and second solutions! I have done that, projecting the field but calling save instead of set... awful mess

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB's shell is powered by a JavaScript Engine. And JavaScript has no type for `integer`. It knows only `Number`, which is a type for floating-point numbers.
You can try using the MongoDB type [`NumberLong`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Overview+-+The+MongoDB+Interactive+Shell#Overview-TheMongoDBInteractiveShell-Numbers), but it didn't work out for me when i once had the same problem.